# Does Abmob Auto Detect When my app uploaded and approved by Apple

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, ads

I am currently adding admob banner to my IOS app. I have already used aduinitID for my bannerView. But I haven't distributed the app yet .When I was testing on real device and simulator, without any doubt, Admob didn't count my request for these banner.

But How can I make sure that when I release the app they would count it for me . 
How will admob detect when my app gets online . Or is there any step that I have to do in advance, or when my app is confirmed that it was approved by apple to notify admob that my app is on store?

By the way, how much money in dollars do I get when displaying banner and Interstitial when using admob? And how much when user touch on the banner .

In addition, can I create several bannerViews but just only lay them on the same position on my Viewcontroller? The point is to increase request in the case displaying banner to make profit.

Answer (score 0):

Statistics admob can greatly delayed. (up to several days), you add your device as a test. Or turn on the test mode in the display.

No steps there. Everything will work out.

0 you get for views. Price per 1,000 views - an exemplary figure income for 1000 shows on the basis of the activity of your users (clicks). You get only for clicks. The price depends on the country the user of the month (advertising budget changes), the time of year, the data about the user, even a lot of things ...

Can. The truth is your application will dislike and hate.

[In addition, SO not the place for such matters.](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)